# mov file playing from the web in adobe air for iOS app

Tags: flash, mov

is it possible to embed a mov file playing from the web in an air for iOS application?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

adobe air can decode in hardware mode only native mp4 videos via stagevideo

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer with more information.  This is a little too short and confusing for a good StackOverflow answer

Comment: Why my answer is short? From my words he must see that Adobe Air can play only native mp4. Where? In iOS because he asking about iOS. How? Via StageVideo. Answer is pretty clear. iOS + Air can't play mov in hardware more. theoretically it can but it's so hard to do so better use mp4 video that works on ios as native video source.